# how can I set a limit for a particular scope if I'm using kaminari

Tags: scope, ruby-on-rails-3.2, kaminari

I'm using the kaminari gem for pagination.

I want to only show the 10 most recent items that were added. For the other scopes I can show up to 30.

Here is the index action of the Resources controller:

```
@filt= params[:filter] || 'no_filter'
      @resources = get_resources(params[:category]||=nil).approved.send(@filt).page(params[:page]).per(30)
```

Here is the scope for the recent Resources added in the Resource.rb model:

```
scope :recent, order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

Because the per(30) is set for the other scopes it overrides the limit in the :recent scope.

How can I only show 10 for the recent scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the order of your function like this :

```
@resources = get_resources(params[:category]||=nil).approved.page(params[:page]).per(30).send(@filt)
```

PS : Instead this `(params[:category]||=nil)` you can simply do this `(params[:category])`

PS2 : I think it's better to create a method class and us it like this :

```
@resources = Resource.find_by_category(params[:category]).approved.page(params[:page]).per(30).send(@filt)
```

Comment: Thank you Dougui. I will apply those changes